# Cannot launch the debugger. The required property 'LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory' is missing or empty

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have the error I wrote in the title when I'm trying to launch the application. I searched with google and I didn't find any page with 'LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory' keyword. The solution contains a mix of c# and c++ projects and it worked fine until today... I use Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010. Do you know where I can find this property to change it or how can I add it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can repro that, your startup project must be a C++ project.  Right-click it, Properties, Debugging, Working Directory setting.  Yours is empty.  The default is $(ProjectDir)